# Problem during extract records XML oracle 11g

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing, oracle11gr2

I am using Oracle 11g
I have a PL/SQL procedure which is reading XML records using XMLTYPE but records does not showing

**XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HOUSEHOLD_DATA><DOCUMENT_iD>105098970</DOCUMENT_iD> 
<discrepancy_p>f</discrepancy_p><HHR_ID>127937684</HHR_ID> 
<ALTERNATE_HEAD>f</ALTERNATE_HEAD><EXPORT_DATE>26-04-2019</EXPORT_DATE> 
<PROVINCE>Gilgit Baltistan</PROVINCE><DISTRICT>astore</DISTRICT> 
<TEHSIL>astore sub-</TEHSIL><PMT_SCORE>22.79597625</PMT_SCORE> 
<VILLAGE>chorit</VILLAGE><UNION_COUNCIL>rehmanpur</UNION_COUNCIL> 
<ADDRESS>chorit</ADDRESS><CONTACT_NO>null</CONTACT_NO><GPS_LOCATION> 
<LONGITUDE></LONGITUDE><LATITUDE></LATITUDE></GPS_LOCATION> 
<BISP_FAMILY_MEMBERS_DATA><BISP_FAMILY_MEMBER_DATA> 
<HHR_ID>127937684</HHR_ID></BISP_FAMILY_MEMBER_DATA> 
</BISP_FAMILY_MEMBERS_DATA></HOUSEHOLD_DATA>
```

**PL/SQL QUERY:**

```
select d.DOCUMENT_iD
, d.discrepancy_p
, d.HHR_ID
, d.ALTERNATE_HEAD
, d.EXPORT_DATE
, s.HHR_ID2
from xmltable(
'/HOUSEHOLD_DATA'
PASSING XMLTYPE(BFILENAME('DATA_UTL_FILE_DIR', '127937684.ready'),
NLS_CHARSET_ID('CHAR_CS'))
columns
DOCUMENT_iD NUMBER                PATH 'DOCUMENT_iD',
discrepancy_p VARCHAR2(1)           PATH 'discrepancy_p',
HHR_ID NUMBER                PATH 'HHR_ID',
ALTERNATE_HEAD VARCHAR2(1)           PATH 'ALTERNATE_HEAD',
EXPORT_DATE VARCHAR2(20)          PATH 'EXPORT_DATE'
) d
, xmltable(
'/BISP_FAMILY_MEMBERS_DATA/BISP_FAMILY_MEMBER_DATA'
PASSING XMLTYPE(BFILENAME('DATA_UTL_FILE_DIR', '127937684.ready'),
NLS_CHARSET_ID('CHAR_CS'))
columns
HHR_ID2 NUMBER                PATH 'HHR_ID2'
) s
;
```

How to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you chain XMLTABLEs like that, it is more efficient to output an XMLTYPE fragment in the first XMLTABLE, which you use in the second. Also, I am assuming that you want to see a row even if there is no HHR_ID2 value, so you need an outer join to the second XMLTABLE.

```
select d.DOCUMENT_iD
, d.discrepancy_p
, d.HHR_ID
, d.ALTERNATE_HEAD
, d.EXPORT_DATE
, s.HHR_ID2
from xmltable(
'/HOUSEHOLD_DATA'
PASSING XMLTYPE(BFILENAME('DATA_UTL_FILE_DIR', '127937684.ready'),
NLS_CHARSET_ID('CHAR_CS'))
columns
DOCUMENT_iD NUMBER                PATH 'DOCUMENT_iD',
discrepancy_p VARCHAR2(1)           PATH 'discrepancy_p',
HHR_ID NUMBER                PATH 'HHR_ID',
ALTERNATE_HEAD VARCHAR2(1)           PATH 'ALTERNATE_HEAD',
EXPORT_DATE VARCHAR2(20)          PATH 'EXPORT_DATE',
BISP XMLTYPE PATH 'BISP_FAMILY_MEMBERS_DATA'
) d
, xmltable(
'/BISP_FAMILY_MEMBERS_DATA/BISP_FAMILY_MEMBER_DATA'
PASSING d.BISP
columns
HHR_ID2 NUMBER                PATH 'HHR_ID'
)(+) s
;
```

Best regards,
Stew Ashton